# Openxlsx loadWorkbook does not return a workbook object

Tags: excel, object, openxlsx

R version 3.6.0

openxlsx version 4.1.4

When loading a workbook with :

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file = myfile.xlsx)
```

return value is not a workbook object but a *Formal class jobjRef* object.

As a consequence, when calling *removeWorksheet* or *addWorksheet* on this object, I get error :

```
Error in removeWorksheet(wb, sheet = sheetname) : 
  wb must be a Workbook object!
```

Until last Friday, it worked fine. Since then, I maybe installed a new version of Java (1.8.0_251). Could it be the reason of the problem?

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem does not occur when package xlsx is not loaded.

There must be an undesired interaction between those packages.